# best/most efficient way to test XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working with big and complex dictionary data (XML) which needs to be parsed by XSL and output XML.

what would be considered as a "best" way to test if XSL is processing all nodes from XML (input)?

please consider this simple example, i think it will represent nature of the problem:

input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
   <b>
      <c>
         some1
         <d>text2</d>
         more text1
      </c>
   </b>
   <b>
      <c>
         some2
         <d>text2</d>
         more text2
      </c>
   </b>
   <d>text3</d>
   <e>
      text
      <d>4</d>
   </e>
</a>
```

some tarnsformations.xsl

output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<amodified>
   <bmodified>
      some1
      <dd>text2</dd>
      more text1
   </bmodified>
   <bmodified>
      some2
      <dd>text2</dd>
      more text2
   </bmodified>
   <dd>text3</dd>
   <ed>text</ed>
   <dd>4</dd>
</amodified>
```

In output.xml names of the tags have been changed as well as order of the content (comparing to input file). 
I need to compare if all text fields from Input are available in output. 
I think the best solution would be to creat test which will extract text from each tag and compare it string by string, outputing tags taht do not exist in output.xml to log file... ?

Comment: A question without a single example isn't constructive. What is "best" and what is "processing all nodes"? My guess is that just processing all nodes isn't what the tests should verify. What about "generating the correct results"? This question, as asked, has very little to do with XSLT and with testing. Please, edit and improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend two kinds of tests: first a unit test on a smaller controlled set of data that is supposed to be a model for the data you find in your large dictionary.  This could be considered a unit test for your xslt process.  I usually would extract several representative pieces from the larger data set, and store these along with the test code.  Then the test applies the transformation to the test data and makes assertions about the result, verifying that the transformation was successfully employed.

Then additionally you should build sanity checks in to your production system so that (for example), you make sure that the total number of nodes processed corresponds to what you expect.  For example, in a dictionary with a large number of entries, you could run one step to count all the entries, and then another one to process them.  Then at the end, see how many entries you processed and make sure the count is the same as what you expected.  This is also useful since it provides a means of outputting a progress bar (% complete).

Anyway, that's what we do.

If the text in the output is the same as the text in the input, as in your example, Marcin, you can compare those fairly easily using xslt.  If you process an xml file with an empty xslt stylesheet (just the `<xslt:stylesheet />` node) then you will get back just the text, with no markup.  I think xmllint can do this too.  So just run that over both your input and output and compare using a simple text comparison (like diff).

Comment: @_Mike: Generally there isn't a 1:1 mapping between the nodes processed and the nodes output. A general solution is to provide a debugging output whenever a node is processed, so that it would be possible to count the "processed indicators" in the final output.

Comment: @Dmitri - that's true; but in many cases you might be able to count the number of expected output nodes and compare.

Comment: @_Mike: Yes, but the question is not how to verify the number of the output nodes. The question is: *How to verify that every input node has been processed*.

Comment: @Dmitri Yes, I understand.  The approach in your answer is to produce some special output that is guaranteed to produce one output node per input node.  I'm suggesting ensuring the actual output is consistent with expectations using some independently computed  property of the expected output, like counting the number of output nodes - very often this may be a function of having correctly processed all the input.  Admittedly that is not universally the case, but especially in a dictionary consisting of basically a list of entries, it is likely to be a good approach?

Comment: @_Mike: To answer your question: Even if the input is a dictionary, if the task requires no corresponding output to be generated for some entries, depending on defined conditions, then by just inspecting the output we cannot find out if every node of the dictionary was processed, or not.

Answer (score 1):

**One can use this technique**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:variable name="vrtfResults">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="num"/>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:variable name="vProcessed" select=
     "count(ext:node-set($vrtfResults)/nodeProcessed)"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vAll" select="count(num)"/>

     <xsl:text>From the existing </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="$vAll"/>
     <xsl:text> &lt;num> elements </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="$vProcessed"/>
     <xsl:text> were processed.</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num">
  <nodeProcessed/>
  <num><xsl:value-of select="2*."/></num>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
From the existing 10 <num> elements 10 were processed.
```

**Explanation**:

1. A special test-only element (`<nodeProcessed/>`) has been added to the processing of every `<num>` element.
2. We capture the output in a variable, then we count the number of `<nodeProcessed/>` elements and compare them to the total number of `<num>` elements that must be processed.